# Classifying critical points without second derivative test

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function, $f$, on $\mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$:

$f(x) = (a_1 x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3) e^{-\left \| x \right \|^{2}}$

It has critical points:

$\left ( 0,0,0 \right )$

$\left ( 0,0,\pm 1 \right )$

$\left ( 0,\pm 1,0 \right )$

$\left (\pm 1,0,0 \right )$

How can I determine whether these points are minimum, maximum, or saddle points without using the second derivative test with a 3x3 Hessian matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The critical points of $f$ are by definition the points $x\in{\mathbb R}^3$ where the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ vanishes.

Since a constant factor is irrelevant for the problem we may assume $a=|1|$. The gradient of the function $$f(x):=(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3)e^{-|x|^2}=\langle a,x\rangle e^{-|x|^2}$$ is given by
$$\nabla f(x)=e^{-|x|^2}\bigl(a-2\langle a,x\rangle\>x\bigr)\ .$$
This can only vanish if $x=\lambda a$ for some $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$. Solving
$a-2 \langle a,\lambda a\rangle\>\lambda a=0$ for $\lambda$ gives $\lambda=\pm{1\over\sqrt{2}}$. We therefore don't have nine critical points, as you propose, but just two of them, namely $$\pm{1\over\sqrt{2}}\>a\ .$$
Writing $x=t\>a+y$ with $y\perp a$ we obtain
$$f(t\>a+y)=t\>e^{-t^2-|y|^2}\ .\tag{1}$$
The well known graph of $t\mapsto t\>e^{-t^2}$ and inspection of $(1)$ then make it obvious that ${1\over\sqrt{2}}a$ is the global maximum and $-{1\over\sqrt{2}}a$ the global minimum of $f$ on ${\mathbb R}^3$.

Comment: I think i for got to mention that $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are constatnts, such that $a_1 > a_2 > a_3 >0$

Comment: Also i dont understand why we are trying to make the gradient "vanish"

Comment: See my edit. I think you don't have the right idea of what a critical point is, or you wouldn't pull nine of them out of a hat.